# How can I put noise to my P3DX model?

Tags: ros, gazebo, p3dx, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ros Users :

I am trying to put noise to my P3DX model wich is https://github.com/RafBerkvens/ua_ros_p3dx
Because the model behaviour is unrealistic.

Does Anybody know what I must modify in the code to do that?

Thanks!!!!

In respose to your comment @Javi V.

I modify this part of the code:

```
 <!-- ground truth -->
<gazebo>
<plugin name="p3d_base_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_p3d.so">
<alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
<updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
<bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
<topicName>${ns}/base_pose_ground_truth</topicName>
<gaussianNoise>0.01</gaussianNoise>
<frameName>map</frameName>
<!-- initialize odometry for fake localization -->
<xyzOffsets>0 0 0</xyzOffsets>
<rpyOffsets>0 0 0</rpyOffsets>
</plugin>
</gazebo>
```

in Gaussian noise but it does the same... any ideas? Do I have to change something else to make this work ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213121/how-can-i-put-noise-to-my-p3dx-model?/) by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-07-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-08**:
Have you taken a look at https://github.com/RafBerkvens/ua_ros_p3dx/blob/master/p3dx_description/urdf/pioneer3dx.gazebo ? Different Gazebo plugins are being used and hopefully you can set noise of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you considered multiplying the data individually by a random number generated from the distribution of your choosing?
Eg a gaussian function  with  mean of 1 and suitably high standard deviation might work well.

---

Originally posted by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) with karma: 327 on 2015-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2015-07-14**:
First of all, thanks for answering.
Where can I find a gaussian function?

**Comment by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) on 2015-07-26**:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/normal_distribution/